# EditText - Get text from EditText while typing

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to get the text into some String in my app while the user is typing in the EditText and use it to lively show it on the activity (in different View...) - Just like google's live/instant search works...

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are looking for `TextWatcher`:

```
    youredittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable mEdit) 
        {
            text = mEdit.toString();
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    });
```