# How to get EditText value to textview at the time of typing without button click in android

Tags: android, android-studio

How to read data from EditText to textview at user input without button click

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditText - Get text from EditText while typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798380/edittext-get-text-from-edittext-while-typing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using textwatcher on Edittext and update textview using available methods.

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int 
            count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};

textView.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Comment: But first entered digit remians as it in in textview please help  !!!

Comment: Ok sir got it i have to check its length if zero then settext to ""

Answer (score 0):

You can add a textwatcher on your edit text, and update your textview from there.