# How to set ontime user input text from EditView to TextView without clicking the button

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext, ontime

I was doing practice and I am stuck at one point that I want to set ontime user input text from EditText to TextView but I don't know how can I do this so I search it here and I found this [How to get EditText value to TextView at the time of typing without button click in android [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067033/how-to-get-edittext-value-to-textview-at-the-time-of-typing-without-button-click)

I follow this but it is not working so that I decided to post a new question to know if any improvement is there or not.

here is my simple XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:inputType="text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my java code

```
package com.example.ontimedata;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv1, tv2;
EditText et1, et2;
String data1, data2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv2 = findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
    et2 = findViewById(R.id.et2);

    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            Log.d("TAG", "beforeTextChanged: ");
            data1 = et1.getText().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onTextChanged: ");
            data1 = et1.getText().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Log.d("TAG", "afterTextChanged: ");
            data1 = et1.getText().toString();
        }
    };
    tv1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    Log.d("TAG", "onCreate: ");


    TextWatcher textWatcher1 = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            data2 = et2.getText().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
    tv2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher1);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance if you answered this.

Answer (score 2):

In Your code You set listener to TextView (`tv1`), You have to add it to EditText (`et1`). You can do it like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView tv1;
    EditText et1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);

        TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(
                    CharSequence s,
                    int start,
                    int count,
                    int after
            )
            {
                Log.d("MyTag",
                      "beforeTextChanged: "
                );
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(
                    CharSequence s,
                    int start,
                    int before,
                    int count
            )
            {
                Log.d("MyTag",
                      "onTextChanged: "
                );
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                Log.d("MyTag",
                      "afterTextChanged: "
                );

                tv1.setText(s); // set TextView text to Text inside EditText
            }
        };

        et1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher); // add Listener to EditText
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Explain briefly. "Ontime user input" is what?
But if you want to change your textView while you type inside your editText.
Just do this inside onTextChanged():

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        textView.setText(editText.getText().toString().trim());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your TextView after getting text from text watcher, need somthing like this:

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        Log.d("TAG", "beforeTextChanged: ");
        //data1 = et1.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onTextChanged: ");
        //data1 = et1.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Log.d("TAG", "afterTextChanged: ");
        String text = s.toString();
        tv1.setText(text)
    }
};
```